# Android design: user-selected parameters for use throughout app

Tags: android, parameters, persistent

I'm creating my first game for Android, using Android Studio, and have a design question about choosing and maintaining parameters throughout the application.

From the main menu, the user would select 'New Game', which opens an Activity called 'New Game Parameters', where they would select one option from each of three categories:

1. Occupation (occupation 1, occupation 2, occupation 3, etc.)
2. Item taken (item 1, item 2, item 3, etc.)
3. Action performed (action 1, action 2, action 3, etc.)

Whatever values the user selects will not change again for that specific play-through once the game starts.  Depending on the choices, different events will occur, and so I'll need to reference these parameters throughout the game.

My question is, what is the best way to design for that?  I've been looking through tons of documentation for BaseAdapter, ArrayAdapter, ListAdapter, Preference, SharedPreference, persistent data, and a lot of it seems viable, but it's been kind of overwhelming and confusing at times.  I've gotten a lot of good information from here before, and appreciate any help that you all can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to save only a few values (like yours, three parameters with values) is SharedPreferences. There is a good and simple example on this page:
[Saving Key-Value Sets](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html#WriteSharedPreference)

You could also implement some constants to give your key fixed values.

Example of your button (or what you want to let the user choose):

```
public void onButtonOption1Click(View v){
      //Save your value
     SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
     SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
     editor.putInt("Occupation",1);
     editor.commit();
}
```

Example of activity where you want to load the value:

```
public void getPreference(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPref=getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int occupation_value =sharedPref.getInt("Occupation");
}
```